# Is this Factory Method the good one for what I'am trying to do?

Tags: php, design-patterns, methods, factory

Here what I'am trying to achieve : 
 - this a text file parser
 - depending on the first chars I create the correct parser object
 - I wish to do so using the right factory pattern
 - could you tell me if my code below fits correctly the factory pattern ?
 - Thank you ! :-)

```
class Parser
{
    protected $src;

    public function __construct($src)
    {
        $this->src = $src;
    }   
}

class Format1Parser extends Parser
{
    public function Parse()
    {
        // Parsing format 1
        // ...
    }
}

class Format2Parser extends Parser
{
    public function Parse()
    {
        // Parsing format 2
        // ...
    }
}

class ParserFactory
{
    public static function GetParser($src)
    {
        $header = substr($src,0,7);
        if ( $header == "format1" )
        {
            return( new Format1Parser($src) );
        }
        if ( $header == "format2" )
        {
            return( new Format2Parser($src) );
        }
        return(false);
    }   
}

$parser = ParserFactory::GetParser( file_get_contents("file.txt") );
$parser->Parse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would use a suffix (Parser_Format1) instead of a prefix (Format1Parser), because IMHO it's clearer.

As for the factory method itself, you could use dynamic instantiation:

```
class ParserFactory {
   static public function getParser($src) {
      // may want to change the following line, because it assumes your parser
      // type is always 7 characters long.
      $type = substr($src, 0, 7); 

      $pattern = 'Parser_%type';
      $className = str_replace('%type', $type, $pattern);
      if (!class_exists($className)) {
         throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid parser $type");

      return new $className;
   } 
}
```

Another thing, your *Parser* class should be abstract and define an abstract function `Parse()`:

```
abstract class Parser {
    protected $src;

    public function __construct($src)
    {
        $this->src = $src;
    }   

    abstract public function Parse();
}
```

Defining abstract methods within a base abstract class ensure that most errors (i.e.: a missing `Parse` method) are caught when the class is parsed (at the beginning of the program), as opposed as to when it's called (in the middle of runtime).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, the code is better like you did. But my question was not good. The good one is "does my code fit correctly the factory method pattern ?", and "is there a better pattern to do this ?"

Comment: Well, the factory pattern's purpose is to create classes of a same type (Parser in this case). So your implementation is good. Like I said, you should just change your `Parser` class to an abstract class, to prevent runtime errors.